# Ncurses 'new_item' function mem leak or what am i doing wrong?

Tags: memory, dictionary, memory-leaks, ncurses

I'm making a calendar in Ncurses, which means I have to dynamically allocate and free memory. The thing is that Valgrind --leak-check=full shows memory leaks in the new_item function. Here is my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
unordered_map<int, ITEM**> 

void NcurInterface::printMenu(GUIITEMS menu, GUIITEMS win)
{   
    typedef ITEM *items;
 // Create items
    int i;
    items *mitem = (ITEM**)new items[manager->getNmbMenuItems(menu) + 1];
    for(i = 0; i < manager->getNmbMenuItems(menu); i++) {
        mitem[i] = new_item(manager->getMenuItemsString(menu, false, i).c_str(), manager->getMenuItemsString(menu, true, i).c_str());
    }
    mitem[i] = ((char)NULL);
    setMenuItems(menu, mitem); // Insert in map
}

void NcurInterface::freeMenuItems(GUIITEMS menu)
{   
    items *clr = menuItems[menu];
        for(unsigned char i = 0; i < manager->getNmbMenuItems(menu) + 1; i++) {
            free_item(clr[i]);
        }
    menuItems.erase(menu);
    delete[] clr;
}
```

Valgrind output

```
1,056 (192 direct, 864 indirect) bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 62 of 92
at 0x4C282B8: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
by 0x5491226: new_item (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmenu.so.5.9)
by 0x4137BC: NcurInterface::printMenu(GUIITEMS, GUIITEMS) (NcurInterface.cpp:220)
by 0x413467: NcurInterface::updateMenu(GUIITEMS, GUIITEMS, GUIITEMS) (NcurInterface.cpp:185)
by 0x417810: main (NcurInterface.cpp:754)
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP wrote:

> Problem solved! The menu has to be unposted first, after that it can be freed and at last items can be freed. No more memory leak!

Comment: ([Question answered in an edit, converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que).)